# Can't delete cells from UITableView, just the data from said cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I am making an app that stores events and their data, and it was working flawlessly until I tried to add Core Data, since then, I've been having issues with it. One is the fact that using the delete func doesn't really delete the tablecell, just the data inside. If I try to delete the blank cell, it does nothing. Below is the code for the delete function I am using.

Also, my app for some reason starts with one of these blank cell, which can't be deleted.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        PersistenceService.context.delete(events[indexPath.row])

        do {
            try PersistenceService.context.save()
            eventLog.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the item from the context **and** from the data source array and it's highly recommended to use `deleteRows` rather than reloading the entire table view to take advantage of the animation

```
PersistenceService.context.delete(events[indexPath.row])
events.remove(at: indexPath.row)
eventLog.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

... save context
```